# How to check user name and last name length in one textfield in android jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

There is an outlinedtextfield where the user enters his/her name and surname, and this outlinetextfield enters the user name and surname, but if the user's name and surname are less than 3 characters, I want to make the border of the outlinetextfield red, but I couldn't figure out how to do this control because space intervened.

for example :

```
a(space)b wrong
jac(space)jac correct
tony(space)stark correct
```

this is my example code:

```
OutlinedTextField(
                    value = state.name,
                    onValueChange = { onChangeName(it) },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = "name and lastname",
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                    },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        focusedBorderColor = if (state.name.length < 7) Color.Red else DefaultDYTColor,
                        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent
                    )
                )
```

When I do it this way, it accepts it as correct even if I type 7 characters without spaces, but it should not be like this.

for example:

```
tonystark
```

According to the code I wrote, this is correct because it is greater than 7 characters

How to achieve this issue ? Do you have any suggestion or solve ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to split the text and each word should have at least 3 characters?

Comment: for example user enter name and last name in textfield. user's name and last name should have at least 3 characters.

Comment: Check the Jan Bína's answer. Note that someone can have 3 names, someone can have a surname with 2 characters....

Comment: yeah thats sound good I didnt think about it. I am enlightened now. I guess Jan Bína's answer is correct but besides Jan Bína's answer how can I make a logic what you said like in this case

Answer (score 0):

This is just an algorithmic problem, you can solve it like this:

```
fun isValidName(name: String): Boolean {
    // split name on each space and filter out those that are blank (consecutive spaces)
    val splits = name.split(" ").filter { it.isNotBlank() }
    // we need at least 2 strings (name and surname)
    // you can also use != 2 if you want exactly 2
    if (splits.size < 2) return false
    // if any name is less than 3 chars, return false
    for (split in splits) {
        if (split.trim().length < 3) {
            return false
        }
    }
    // now we have at least 2 names and all of them have 3 or more chars
    return true
}
```

Comment: You could use the `any` method and a shorthand method to have a cleaner code : 

`fun isValidName(name: String): Boolean = name
    .split(" ")
    .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
    .any {
        it.trim().length < 3
    }`

Comment: yeah sure, but I wanted more "basic" solution, since OP is clearly beginner